# WCF Routing load balancing with throttling

Tags: c#, wcf, routes, load-balancing, throttling

Can I integrate throttling in WCF routing?

For example, I had an 2 endpoint in the router

> main endpoint: 192.168.1.90:30000 backup endpoint: 192.168.1.80:30000

Can I set a throttling behavior in the router so that if the main endpoint already have 100 concurrent sessions it will automatically point the next session into the backup endpoint?

How can I implement it in C# in NetTcpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

As I think this approach is not quite correct: to load one server at max level and switch to another server after. I think it is better to load both servers using round robin algorithm. You can find a good article [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/c942e8b6-30dc-407d-a829-19a8d4e96331/load-balancing-and-custom-filters-in-wcf-40-routing-services?forum=wcf).